# vuetifyjs-nuxt: can not add any UI component

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am using [vuetifyjs/nuxt](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/nuxt) starter template.

It launches correctly, however when I try to add a [`<Bagde />`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/badges) UI componenent to the [***default.vue***](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/nuxt/blob/master/template/layouts/default.vue) inside the `<v-toolbar />` component, I am getting this error:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component
>   correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"
>   option.

In fact, this happens whenever I want to add a UI component ([UI component API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/api-explorer)). What am I missing here?

EDIT:

From [default.vue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/nuxt/blob/master/template/layouts/default.vue) file:

I want to add:

```
<v-badge left>
        <span slot="badge">6</span>
        <v-icon
          large
          color="grey lighten-1"
        >
          shopping_cart
        </v-icon>
      </v-badge>
```

inside `<v-toolbar>` below:

```
<template>
    <!-- rest of code -->
    <v-toolbar fixed app :clipped-left="clipped">
      <v-toolbar-side-icon @click="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-btn
        icon
        @click.stop="miniVariant = !miniVariant"
      >
        <v-icon v-html="miniVariant ? 'chevron_right' : 'chevron_left'"></v-icon>
      </v-btn>

       <!-- Added here -->

        <v-badge left>
    <span slot="badge">6</span>
    <v-icon
      large
      color="grey lighten-1"
    >
      shopping_cart
    </v-icon>
  </v-badge>
      <!-- end of the badge I added -->
      <v-btn
        icon
        @click.stop="clipped = !clipped"
      >
        <v-icon>web</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn
        icon
        @click.stop="fixed = !fixed"
      >
        <v-icon>remove</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-toolbar-title v-text="title"></v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn
        icon
        @click.stop="rightDrawer = !rightDrawer"
      >
        <v-icon>menu</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: Error only appears when you add `v-badge`? Did you import the component in the first place?

Comment: Please add your script tag to know if you import Badge component.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ You did choosed a a-la-carte setup during project create, right?

Comment: @Traxo I have to import that Badge componenet first? Is not it available by default as it is a part of vuetify.js library which is registered globaly for this template?

Comment: @Aldarund Yes, I did. Is that the source of my problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's imported by default. You are probably using `a-la-carte` so you must register everything manually.

Comment: Indeed, during the installation I picked that weird `a la carte` without understanding what it means, so I have to google about it, thank you @Traxo

Comment: Thank you for the link @Traxo but in this template everything is pre-configured correctly, so I believe what you and Aldarund  said previously is the source of this issue

Comment: Yes, but essentially the problem and solution(s) are the same as far as I can see, so I flagged it as a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, this is the first day I am trying to use vuetify @Traxo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like u choosed [a-la-carte setup](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/guides/a-la-carte) during project creation. It means that only components that are used are imported. So if you want to use other components than you need to go to plugins/vuetify.js and add it there. Or if you remove then altogether and leave only

```
Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

And also remove transform-imports from nuxt.config. Than all components will be available. But it will also increase bundle size as expected

Comment: Ok, so I will do a new installation without choosing that `a la carte` option, and this should work hopefully. I will read that link in a moment. Thank you very much