# Vue/Vuetify - Unknown custom element: did you register the component correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

My question is very similar to [[Vue/Vuetify - Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298751/vue-vuetify-unknown-custom-element-v-app-did-you-register-the-component-c/50299502]) but there **is** a difference!

I made a custom vue component which uses vuetify components (v-sheet, v-card, etc) and following this [guide](https://medium.com/justfrontendthings/how-to-create-and-publish-your-own-vuejs-component-library-on-npm-using-vue-cli-28e60943eed3) I made the component available via npm.

In my nuxt application I import the component from the library and register it in a page.

Then I get the warnings about v-components not being registered recursively. My custom component is named. My nuxt application uses vuetify.

If I add

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

at the top of my custom component's script tag (as suggested in the linked SO post), this does not solve the issue.

If I add it in default.vue (for nuxt layout) it does.

In my entry point `index.js` I have

```
import Vue from 'vue';

// I have tried adding vuetify here

import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent.vue';


const components = {
  MyComponent
}

function install(Vue) {
  if (install.installed) return;
  install.installed = true;
// I have tried adding vuetify here
  Object.keys(components).forEach(name => {
// I have tried adding vuetify here
    Vue.component(name, components[name])
  });
}

const plugin = {
  install,
}

let GlobalVue = null;
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  GlobalVue = window.Vue;
} else if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
  GlobalVue = global.Vue;
}
if (GlobalVue) {
// I have tried adding vuetify here
  GlobalVue.use(plugin);
// I have tried adding vuetify here
}


export default components
export {
  MyComponent
}
```

how do I fix this so that I do not have to reload vuetify in my nuxt app?

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52246320/vuetifyjs-nuxt-can-not-add-any-ui-component

Comment: @Traxo related yes, the issue no. I have vuetify as a plugin in my nuxt app and the lack of vuetify being registered is an issue whether or not it is vue-cli, codesandbox or nuxt.

Comment: @SumNeuron Did you solve your problem? Happens to me only when I build a server (express) with nuxt app